# Is it possible that in Fotorama arrows can change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fotorama

I need to change arrows slider of `Fotorama` library. Is that possible? I read documentation, but can not find anything.

[image]

My codes

```
  <div id="fotorama" class="fotorama" data-width="100%" data-allowfullscreen="native"
                        data-transition="slide" data-arrows="true" data-click="true" data-swipe="true" data-keyboard="true"
                        data-clicktransition="dissolve" data-nav="thumbs" data-autoplay="true">
                        <img
                            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1555636222-cae831e670b3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1477&q=80">
                        <img
                            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494526585095-c41746248156?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80">
                        <img
                            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554223818-aef3e2944be2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1474&q=80">
                    </div>
```

I tried in jquery but did not work

```
$('#fotorama').fotorama({
 arrowPrev: '<img src="/path-to-image/Previous.png" width="30" height="30" >',
 arrowNext: '<img src="/path-to-image/Next.png" width="30" height="30" >'
});
```

Comment: You implementing this in Magento?

Comment: @VivekK. no Laravel.

Comment: I don't see any options in documentation https://fotorama.io/docs/4/options/ to set arrow HTML, you'll have to change it using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Do this to set nav images

```
$(".fotorama__arr--prev").css("background-image", "url(path/to/prev.png)");
$(".fotorama__arr--next").css("background-image", "url(path/to/next.png)");
```

You can also use jquery `when` to apply `prev & next` after `fotorama` is loaded

```
$(function () {
  $.when($('#fotorama').fotorama(options)).then(function(){
     $(".fotorama__arr--prev").css("background-image", "url(path/to/prev.png)");
     $(".fotorama__arr--next").css("background-image", "url(path/to/next.png)");
  });
});
```

Or do it in `CSS` without `jQuery`

```
.fotorama__arr--prev{
  background-image: url(path/to/prev.png) !important;
}
.fotorama__arr--next{
  background-image: url(path/to/next.png) !important;
}
```